# Function to search array and return boolean value excel

Tags: arrays, formula, excel-365

How can I search an array of safety values and return a boolean value/message if a values in this array are greater than a given safety value?

So far I just used a simple IF statement:

`=IF(H10:J12>K10,"Safety concern identified","No Safety concern Identified")`

However this returns the result for each value of the array. Instead I just want a single cell to return if Any of the values exceed the limit. Is there a function that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(COUNTIF(H10:J17,">"&K10)>0,"Safety Concern Identified","No Safety Concern Identified")`

For anyone looking for a simple answer `COUNTIF` function can achieve this